# how to use jquery to change background color of textbox for 3 seconds?

Tags: jquery, forms, time, submit

I'm doing a textbox and if the requirements does not meet then the background will change to yellow but I only want the background to stay yellow for 3 seconds....how can I do that?

This is what I have at the moment but the yellow bg stays...

```
$("#form").on("submit",function(){


user = $("#username").val().length;
userErrorBg = $('#username').css('background','yellow');


if(user < 3 || user > 6)
{

    setInterval("userErrorBg",0);

}

})
```

I'm thinking of putting a clearInterval somewhere but I will need a time count right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use `setTimeout(function(){},time)` if you suppose it to work only once in a specific time period instead of `setInterval(function(){}, time)` which repeats the function after a specific time period given.

Try this:

```
$("#form").on("submit", function () {
    user = $("#username").val().length;
    if (user < 3 || user > 6) {
       $('#username').css('background', 'yellow'); //<---need to put it here
       setTimeout(function () {
           $('#username').css('background', 'white').focus(); //<--add focus too
       }, 3000);
       return false;
    } 
});
```

#### [CHECKOUT THE DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VSPep/)

#### [This POST could help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval).

Comment: Hey have you found some issue here.

Comment: haha ya...I realized it's weird why my userErrorBg isn't inside the if statement and it'll still have yellow background too....

Comment: and so now even if the user is within 3-6 characters the bg will still turn yellow...which really doesn't matter because after submitting the page will load to other pages too but I'm just curious and thinking about it before asking again:P

Comment: @user1850712 Oh yes great catch but i fixed it and you can take out the fiddle link too.

Comment: but I'm really curious why would it run if I put it outside if statement and it's being set as a variable after submit...instead of telling it to run it on submit...

Comment: or if I want to make it a variable I should put it outside the sumbit function?

Comment: Well i think javascript functions runs even they are set in the variables because they are complete function not a string or obj (i guess).

Comment: No that won't work either. better to put it at correct place.

Comment: so I guess setting it into var. wouldn't help much :P if I'm only using it once or twice

Comment: I just tried putting it outside the submit function and the bg just changes to yellow automatically when I load the page :P

Comment: i guess yes! you can store an object or arrays of object in.

Comment: yeah that is because of a complete function of css applied and fired at page load event.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using [setTimout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead of [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). The setTimeout is fired once and does not repeat it self and you wont need to clear interval as you have to for `setInterval`.

```
setTimout(function(){
    $('#username').css('background','white');
},3000);
```

Comment: I did try setTimeout but the bg just stays instead of gone after 3000

Comment: You have to reset it in setTimeout function, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form").on("submit",function(){
```

try this-

```
user = $("#username").val().length;
userErrorBg = $('#username').css('background','yellow').delay(3000).css('background','white');


if(user < 3 || user > 6)
{

    setInterval("userErrorBg",0);

}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$("#form").on("submit",function(){


user = $("#username").val().length; 


if(user < 3 || user > 6)
{

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#username').css('background','yellow');
    },0);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#username').css('background','white');
    },3000);
}

});
```